# How to make a table in a table

Tags: mysql

I want to crate a table `Person` in mysql which has the values: `Name`, `ID`, `Password`, some other information and a table called `items` which has the values of `Item`,`price`, `stock` so each `Person` would have its information and a table of items that is unique for this exact `Person`.

So it would look something like this.

```
+------+-------+-------+
| ID   | Name  | Pass  |
+------+-------+-------+-+
| 1165 | Exc   |Itm|Pr|St|    
|      |       +---------+
+------+-------| Sc|20|1 |
               +---------+
```

I would be interested if it could be done in MYSQL, if it's not possible, what is possible for my situation.

Comment: You are describing 2 different tables... what is stopping you from defining each one? and then looking for `JOIN`

Comment: There are JSON type fields as of MySQL 5.7 - while not a table, they do allow a data structure within a field as you are describing. See here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json.html

Comment: create the two tables. In the second one add a column person_id where you store the id of the person the item belongs to. Then with JOIN you can get all the informations linked together

Comment: if you'd studied basic database design and table relationships you'd instantly know how to structure this already. You need two tables - one for person, one for items, with a foreign key relationship between them using the person ID. Then to retrieve the data you can write a query to link them together using a JOIN. And please take a general introductory course in relational databases before you go any further, then you can understand the most basic principles of what you're doing. P.S. None of this is specific to mysql, all relational database engines share the same concept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two tables, with a foreign key constraint.

As a simplistic example, the person table

```
CREATE TABLE person 
( id     INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY COMMENT 'PK'
, name   VARCHAR(30)
) ENGINE=InnoDB
;
```

and the item table

```
CREATE TABLE item 
( id         INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY COMMENT 'PK'
, person_id  INT NOT NULL             COMMENT 'FK ref person.id'
, item       VARCHAR(30)
, price      DECIMAL(20,2)
, stock      DECIMAL(18,0)
, CONSTRAINT FK_item_person FOREIGN KEY (person_id)
  REFERENCES person (id) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB
```

This implements a one-to-many relationship.  A person can have zero, one or more item. An item belongs to exactly one person.

```
INSERT INTO person (id, name)  VALUES 
  (1165,'Exc')
, (1066,'Foo')
;

INSERT INTO item (id, person_id, item, price, stock) VALUES 
  ( 42, 1165, 'Sc', 20, 1 )
, ( 43, 1066, 'Ba', 12, 11 )
, ( 44, 1066, 'Co',  3, 2 )
;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE Person (
    ID int,
    Name varchar(100),
    Pass varchar(100),
    PRIMARY KEY ID);

CREATE TABLE Item(
    ID int,
    Item varchar(100),
    Price varchar(100),
    Stock varchar(100),
    FOREIGN KEY (ID) REFERENCES Person(ID)
);
```

those create 2 different tables.
This selects all and joins them.

```
 Select * from Persons p
    inner join Item i on p.ID = i.ID
```